# What is the naming convention for a single var namespace in clojure/clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, naming-conventions, clojurescript

I often find myself defining namespaces in clojurescript that contain only a single var created via def or defn that I'll be using outside of that namespace.

This is especially common when using [reagent](/questions/tagged/reagent), where I define my components in separate files/namespaces and I only ever use these single components outside the namespace.

```
(ns project.components.component-name)
(defn component-name ...)
```

So I import them this way, and I find it pretty repetitive and unclear as there is one name used for both namespace and component:

```
project.components.component-name :as [component-name]

component-name/component-name
```

or inferior :refer (because it's less obvious that var come's from another namespace)

```
project.components.component-name :refer [component-name]

component-name
```

I know that there is a useful pattern for this in ECMAScript:

```
export default function () { ... };
```

So is there anything like this in Clojure? Or maybe there is some established convention for this?

Below is the convention I started to use recently and I'm very unsure about it.

```
(ns project.components.component-name)
(defn _ ...)

project.components.component-name :as [component-name]
```

Then use it as

```
component-name/_
```

Answer (score 1):

An underscore is typically used for a value you don't care about in Clojure so I'd strongly suggest you avoid use of `_` as a function name. For example, you'll often see code in the wild like this:

```
;; Maybe when destructuring a let. Kinda contrived example.
(let [[a _ _ d] (list 1 2 3 4)]
   (+ a d 10))

;; Quite often in a protocol implementation where we don't care about 'this'.
(defrecord Foo []
  SomeProtocol
  (thing [_ x]
    (inc x)))
```

There's nothing wrong with having a single var in a namespace, although I would probably only introduce a namespace when there's a reasonable chunk of functionality. You could try a namespace like `my-app.components` where you keep all the little bits until they're big enough to warrant a dedicated space. Something along the lines of this:

```
(ns my-app.components
  ;; The profile stuff is really big lets say.
  (:require [my-app.components.profile :as profile]))

(defn- items->ul
  [items]
  [:ul (map #(vector :li (:text %)) items)])

(defn- render-nav
  [state]
  [:nav (-> state deref :nav-items items->ul)])

(defn- render-footer
  [state]
  [:footer (-> state deref :footer-items items->ul)])

(defn render-layout
  [state]
  [:html
   [:head [:title (:title @state)]]
   [:body
    [:main
     (render-nav state)
     (profile/render-profile (-> state deref :current-user))
     (render-footer state)]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure one component per namespace is the best approach. This will result
in a large number of namespaces and considerable repetition. However, this is
clojure and everyone has a different style. My approach is to use the namespaces
to break up things along functionality. With all but the vary simplest
components, I find it vary rare that a component won't also use other
components. I will tend to group together all the components used in a
particular function and for vary low level components which are used in most
other components, have a /utility/ or /base/ namespace. For example, I might
have something like

```
project --|
          src --|
                my-app --|
                         core.cljs
                         interface --|
                                     base.cljs
                                     navbar.cljs
                                     sidebar.cljs
                                     tabber.cljs
```

In each of those namespaces, there may be multiple components. Some of them may
be defined as private to that namespace and others are the entry component which
is referenced by core.cljs. I find namespace require sections don't get too
large or repetitive and I don't need to jump around in different files as much
YMMV.